# Access class context in lambda function passed in constructor

Tags: lambda, kotlin

I have created a class that takes an input parameter which is a lambda function:

```
class MyClass(var onClick: () -> Unit) {
    private val title = SomeComponent()

    init {
        // register some listeners that finally invokes `onClick`
        // for simplicity, let's assume:

        title.addKeyListener(object : KeyListener {
            override fun keyPressed(e: KeyEvent?) {
                onClick()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This `MyClass` is initialized with the `onClick` provided:

```
val instance = MyClass(
    onClick = {
        // some logic
    }
)
```

Is it possible to access the class context from inside the `onClick` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you could give `onClick` `MyClass` as receiver.

```
class MyClass(var onClick: MyClass.() -> Unit) { //...

    init {
        //...
        onClick()
        //...
    }
}

fun main() {
    MyClass { 
        // "this" is the instance of MyClass here
    }
}
```

In the `init` block you have three options to invoke `onClick()`:

```
this.onClick()
onClick(this)
onClick() // is invoked on this, but this is omitted
```

I would go with the last one.